# How to check if a set is a subset of another set

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Here's my SQL problem. I have 2 tables:
User Table:

```
[UserID]   [Access]  
Abe        A
Abe        B
Brad       C
Cathy      A
```

Role Lookup Table:

```
[Role]      [Access]
Admin       A
Admin       B
ReadOnly    C
```

I need to check if a user has all the Accesses of a Role, and end up a table like this:

```
[UserID]   [Role}
Abe        Admin
Brad       ReadOnly
Cathy      None
```

In addition, a user can have multiple Roles, as long as it has all the Accesses of these Roles.

Can anyone point me the direction? Showing me the logic or basic method would be helpful enough. I'd need to code this in T-SQL. Thanks!

Comment: What if a user has accesses for multiple roles?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, if could have multiple Roles. Then this user will have multiple rows in the result. I've added this to the question. thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all roles that user has access to as:

```
select u.userid, r.role
from users u join
     roles r
     on u.access = r.access
group by u.userid, r.role
having count(*) = (select count(*) from roles r2 where r2.role = r.role);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! Totally works, and fast. Thanks!